# How to handle a "two or more dot url" with nodejs

Tags: node.js, url, routes

I would like to handle with node js an url like this one : "music.youtube.com" like we would do with an url with parameters. I verified, and youtube.com and  music.youtube.com have the same ip so they're on the same domain name. (I couldn't verify the port, but I think they're the same too)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: URLs like `http://music.youtube.com` are done with subdomains in DNS.  How to set up a subdomain depends upon who you are using for a DNS hosting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to be a bit cleared in your question but with that said..

Just because they have the 'same' IP, does not mean they are on the 'same' domain or 'server' for that matter.

Most enterprise application will be behind a WAF (web application firewall) that will act as a proxy before any and all request come in. They will read the incoming request, check for malicious actions etc and choose to forward the request to the destination server or not.

So on the DNS level, you would have all your domains pointing to a 'range' of IP's that are essentially the WAF, the WAF then has routing instructions on where it should go (A record or CName). This typically will then inspect traffic, if ok it will forward onto the coreect IP or CName with headers containing information like IP etc (this is where proxypass in NGINX comes in for logging etc)

Now that we have a bit of background out of the way..

If your application is 'different' depending on the URL then you should look at setting up 'two' distinct applications and run them separately. While it is possible to run these on the same server the question would be why?

Why is the question why? Well, if they are in-deed separate then you don't want them competing for the same resources / event loop, yes you can run them as two separate application on the same box but again, why? You are better served by spinning up another box with resources dedicated to that application, this way you have more control and separation of concerns (if app one is having issues it wont crash application 2)

On the inverse, if the URL is more of a vanity URL then you would simply set up redirect rules in your NGINX config to simply pass the URL subdmain.tld.xyz to the correct page in your application.